# are Java collections supported in the port from processing to processing.js?

Tags: java, processing, processing.js

This point is unclear from the doc: are Java collections supported in the port from processing to processing.js? I have some Processing code that uses sets and maps and I would love to avoid refactoring it into arrays if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Java collections don't (for the most part) have direct equivalents in JavaScript, supporting them in Processing.js would require a lot of work.

ArrayList and HashMap are most likely supported because they're the closest to any implementations in native JavaScript, namely [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).  I see that the [Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/) says they're "working towards a 100% compatible API, allowing all native Java code to run in Javascript", but I would take this to mean all native Java code used by Processing and its core classes.  Attempting to port [all of native Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) to run in JavaScript is definitely outside the scope for the Processing.js project.

That said, enforcing the rules of Java collection interfaces like Set and Map *is* technically possible in JavaScript, so it's not out of the realm of future possibility...

Comment: And apparently ECMAScript 6 promises support for Sets and Maps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla#Features_already_supported so it's even more possible to think that someday Processing.js will too.  But...not yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/), only equivalents for `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are provided.